# Angular binding for tel number

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I trying to bind a telephone number which comes from a Json object loaded from a server. What's my mistake?

```
<a ng-href="tel:{{card.phone}}"><i class="fa fa-phone redicon fa-2x"></i></a>
```

This is the data:

```
"phone": "+4199999999",
```

Comment: if you want to display the number you need to add it  <a>Here</a>

Comment: @HaikelO Thanks, but that's not my goal. I want that if the user clicks the icon the should go to the phone to call this number.

Comment: Remove {{}} from `ng-href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for interpolation with angular directives (such as `ng-href`):

```
<a ng-href="tel:card.phone"><i class="fa fa-phone redicon fa-2x"></i></a>
```

Comment: Good luck with the app

Comment: Another thing to notice is ng-href just works within tag </a>.

Answer (score 1):

If Phone number is not being detected then you might want to check for following line in header part

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

OR you can set

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
```

to get it working.

Regards.