# Angular JS "<a href='tel:{num} '> call me</a> hyperlink does not work

Tags: angularjs, html

While trying to render the hyper link using Angular JS it does not generate the hyper link. All other tags like `<p>` or `<h2>` work fine, but href fails.

```
var tempString = "<a href='tel:{mob_number}'>call me support</a>"
```

actual output - string is displayed but hyperlinked is not rendered. It's not clickable. Inspect page display tag generated as

```
<a> call me support </a>
```

Expected output - should display string with hyperlink.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular binding for tel number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919813/angular-binding-for-tel-number)

Comment: hi Maher,
thanks for your search but i have already incorporated the comments mention this thread . The numbers are printed and dislayed fine but some how the href tag is not getting populated when we try to parse the HTML code using string variable in angular JS.

Comment: So please set your codes, like controller code and html, this can help you to improve the question and get correct answer.

Comment: Add ng-href instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to do this by 3 mood "`Html`, `directive`, `bind-html`"

> Directive not work `stackoverflow`, try it on your local

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);


app.controller("ctrl", [
  "$scope", "$sce",
  function($scope, sce) {
    $scope.mob_number = "123";

    var tempString = "<a href=\"tel:" + $scope.mob_number + "\">call me support</a>";
    $scope.asHtmlTemplate = sce.trustAsHtml(tempString);
  }
]);

app.directive("mobile", function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "mobile.html",
    scope: {
      content: "@",
      mobNumber: "="
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h4>simple html</h4>
  <a ng-href="tel:{{mob_number}}">call me support</a>

  <h4>as directive [directive not display in stackoverflow]</h4>
  <mobile mob_number="mob_number" content="call me support"></mobile>
  <!-- directive not display in stackoverflow ? -->

  <h4>as Html template from controller</h4>
  <div ng-bind-html="asHtmlTemplate"></div>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="mobile.html">
    <a ng-href='tel:{{mobNumber}}'>{{content}}</a>
  </script>
</div>
```